# Not getting correct SUM amount for users votes from thread and reply table

Tags: codeigniter

I am using codeigniter 3.1.0 and I am trying to get the total SUM of two columns from different tables

If my **user_id = 1** it should return the total sum of **421** but returns **431** It is adding the votes from other users on my reply table

> **Question** Using Active Record How can I make sure the SUM is getting the correct amount for the users id.

Model Function

```
public function thread_reputation($user_id) {
    $this->db->select('SUM(reply.votes + thread.votes) AS reputation');
    $this->db->from('thread', 'left');
    $this->db->join('reply', 'reply.user_id = thread.user_id', 'left');
    $this->db->where('thread.user_id', $user_id);
    $this->db->where('reply.user_id', $user_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->row();
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Controller section where i echo it

```
$thread_reputation = $this->thread_analytics_model->thread_reputation('1');
echo $thread_reputation->reputation;
```

Thread Table

[image]

Reply Table

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query with this

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT SUM(A.votes) as reputation from
    (
      SELECT reply.votes FROM reply where reply.user_id = $user_id

      UNION ALL

      SELECT thread.votes FROM thread where thread.user_id = $user_id               
    )AS A");
```

Tested and properly working

Check Screenshot:-
[image]

Query using **ACTIVE REOCRD**

```
$this->db->select("SUM(A.votes) as reputation");
$this->db->from("(
SELECT reply.votes FROM reply where reply.user_id = $user_id

UNION ALL

SELECT thread.votes FROM thread where thread.user_id = $user_id) AS A");
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: Can it be done in CI http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html way

Comment: just check query and let me know if it's giving proper output then after I will convert it in CI

Comment: Why you dont want to use $this->db->query()

Comment: @wolfgang1983 hey check I have added active record query

Comment: I have another solution as well have added my answer to it is using active records.

Answer (score 0):

Another Solution using `$this->db->get_compiled_select();`

```
public function reputation($user_id) {
    $this->db->select('thread.votes');
    $this->db->from('thread');
    $this->db->where('thread.user_id ='  . $user_id);
    $thread_query = $this->db->get_compiled_select();
    $this->db->select('reply.votes');
    $this->db->from('reply');
    $this->db->where('reply.user_id ='. $user_id);
    $reply_query = $this->db->get_compiled_select();

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT SUM(total.votes) as reputation from ($reply_query UNION ALL $thread_query) as total");

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->row();
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

When you will use left join, it will return matched column & all other unmatched column from left table. Use **inner join** & check your result.