# Codeigniter active record for simple query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Please see the following query.

I want to convert it into codeIgniter active records.

**SQL QUERY:**

```
$this->db->query("SELECT SUM(A.votes) as reputation from
(
      SELECT reply.votes FROM reply where reply.user_id = $user_id

      UNION ALL

      SELECT thread.votes FROM thread where thread.user_id = $user_id               
)AS A");
```

How can I convert this without using $this->db->query()?

The ActiveRecord style of querying with CodeIgniter escapes parameters, but not `db->query()` and also `db->query()` is not SQL Injection protected by default.

That's why I want to convert it using codeigniter active records.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are asking a question off my one I think you have added this as a question instead of answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40055401/not-getting-correct-sum-amount-for-users-votes-from-thread-and-reply-table

Comment: u already know that query is properly working

Comment: No it is not sorry

Comment: @wolfgang1983 using active record query and simple query both are working

Answer (score 0):

Found solution regarding my problem

Query using **ACTIVE RECORD**

```
$this->db->select("SUM(A.votes) as reputation");
$this->db->from("(
SELECT reply.votes FROM reply where reply.user_id = $user_id

UNION ALL

SELECT thread.votes FROM thread where thread.user_id = $user_id) AS A");
$query = $this->db->get();
```